# moment js time formatting with custom time format as inputs

Tags: javascript, momentjs, time-format

input format can be, hh:mm OR hh OR hh:mm:ss OR hh:mm A/hh A/hh:mm:ss
how it can be formatted on same inline as "hh:mm:ss A" format.

How can we format using moment js. Or its not feasible input for moment js time formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with the [Format method](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

[DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-agnesi-2rvw9?file=/src/index.js:0-203)

```js
import moment from "moment";

let date = new Date();
let time = date.getTime();

moment(time).format("hh:mm:ss A");
```

Comment: When applying `{moment('2020/-0/5-23T23:32:10Z','hh:mm:ss A').format("hh:mm:ss A")` , it gets output as `08:32:10 PM`  , is it considering UTC, not sure what will be the correct time in UTC even.  this one is one of the possible input.

Comment: @dsi I'm pretty sure you're parsing it passing in an explicit format it should be interpreted as. Try instead: `moment('2020/-0/5-23T23:32:10Z').format('hh:mm:ss A')` -- But do note that slashes aren't valid in an ISO time string to my knowledge.